# Shortest path between start and end point with many other points in between

Tags: qgis, point, line, path

Sorry if double post, but I haven't found this specific problem in the search function. I want qgis to show me the shortest path (direct) between many points with each point only is hit once. There is also a start point and an end point.

[image: Given points with start and end]

So that it looks like this (just an example and obviously NOT the shortest path)

[image]

Comment: Are you thinking of Djikstra's Algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm? That does not pass through every point but does find the shortest path.. in implementation a path passing through all points is considered but discarded for being longer than a more direct path, so the same logic applies but a path only becomes valid if it passes through each point once then compare the lenghts of the valid paths and retain the shortest.

Comment: No, every point should be hit once. Although this is also very interesting, thanks!

Comment: If you started with a Delaunay triangulation http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DelaunayTriangulation.html you could extract the edges and look at this as as a shortest path delivery problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem which lists methods (Djikstra's among them). Conceptually the edges would be the roads and points delivery locations, so none can be skipped, a shortest path is sought to minimize the travel for the driver.

Comment: This is traveling salesperson problem. Going to nearest first usually works.

Comment: and how would i do that?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257299/49538